# Stack Exchange в видео формате с @Марк Из и @Nick Volynkin. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: предложение, видеочат

С радостью спешу сообщить, что в ближайший понедельник (24–го апреля) в 17:26 по московскому времени состоится первый выпуск видеочата, в котором мы познакомимся с:

- [@Марк Из](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1067/), модератор сообщества Русский язык;
- [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), модератор сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yq6kUTfJxhc
Вы сможете задать свои вопросы участникам диалога в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) ([альтернативный чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/) для сообщества Русский язык). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky`, чтобы я мог своевременно отреагировать на вопрос и задать его ребятам. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам мне на почту заранее (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com).

С нетерпением ждем Вас!

Comment: 17:26? Недостаточно точно, напишите секунды.

Comment: 1. Почему 17:26? 2. Почему именно эти модераторы?

Comment: а чего так рано-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy Время выбрано с учетом разницы в часовых поясах. В будущем, было бы очень здорово провести подобные встречи с многими участниками!

Comment: Закинул в доску событий

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что мы нашли время, а другие пока не нашли.

Comment: Я не могу в 17:26, давайте перенесём на 17:28?

Comment: @vp_arth смотрите трансляцию через диалап, как раз будет задержка в пару минут. )

Comment: @vp_arth пока секунды не указаны, можно надеяться, что время будет 17:26:120. Тогда не придется свои дела бросать на половине.

Comment: Сколько по времени это продлится?

Comment: 1 апреля продолжается?

Comment: @Other, говорят, что примерно 1:36:371 - 1:36:385. Прости за не очень точный результат, но конкретнее не знаю.

Comment: Трансляция через час а ссылка так и не была добавлена.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, ну так и трансляция еще не началась

Comment: @Grundy тогда не стоило использовать оборот "чуть-чуть позже", если ссылка будет доступна только непосредственно после начала события.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, но там же не указано на сколько чуть-чуть :-)

Comment: Очень понравилось ребята, круто. Это интересная тема, и, имхо, все только за, чтобы таких встреч было как можно больше. В целом было очень интересно слушать все истории из вашей жизни, - и есть в этом какой-то кайф, послушать и посмотреть на людей, чьи ники видишь каждый день, а кто за ними скрывается....)